# MongoDB - PyMongo Read Performance Enhancement

Tags: python, mongodb, database-performance

I notice my read performance slowed way down in recent weeks as I've started doing more writes to the primary node. Adding documents and updating documents. After doing a bit of troubleshooting and testing I've found that modifying the read_preference for either the client session, database, or collection has a significant effect.

Based on this [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference-mechanics/#replica-set-read-preference-behavior-nearest), I would have thought that read performance NEAREST would have been the quickest. However it would appear that SECONDARY is the quickest. Does anyone have any insight and possibly additional recommendations for further enhancements? Such as disabling Causal Consistency?

**Findings:**

*Setting Read Preference to PRIMARY*

```
%%timeit
#html_collection = html_collection.with_options(read_preference=ReadPreference.PRIMARY)
print(html_collection.read_preference)
start = time.time()
print(len(list(html_collection.find())),'documents')
end = time.time()
print(end - start,'seconds')

Primary()
29 documents
17.630228757858276 seconds
Primary()
29 documents
17.821024894714355 seconds
Primary()
29 documents
18.69744086265564 seconds
Primary()
29 documents
17.730278730392456 seconds
Primary()
29 documents
17.81557846069336 seconds
Primary()
29 documents
17.49613308906555 seconds
Primary()
29 documents
17.80984354019165 seconds
Primary()
29 documents
17.650660753250122 seconds
17.9 s ± 359 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

*Setting Read Preference to NEAREST*

```
%%timeit
#html_collection = html_collection.with_options(read_preference=ReadPreference.NEAREST)
print(html_collection.read_preference)
start = time.time()
print(len(list(html_collection.find())),'documents')
end = time.time()
print(end - start,'seconds')

Nearest(tag_sets=None, max_staleness=-1)
29 documents
2.463563919067383 seconds
Nearest(tag_sets=None, max_staleness=-1)
29 documents
1.559664011001587 seconds
Nearest(tag_sets=None, max_staleness=-1)
29 documents
18.120014429092407 seconds
Nearest(tag_sets=None, max_staleness=-1)
29 documents
2.6866166591644287 seconds
Nearest(tag_sets=None, max_staleness=-1)
29 documents
2.0677454471588135 seconds
Nearest(tag_sets=None, max_staleness=-1)
29 documents
2.548630714416504 seconds
Nearest(tag_sets=None, max_staleness=-1)
29 documents
1.5781867504119873 seconds
Nearest(tag_sets=None, max_staleness=-1)
29 documents
1.5037789344787598 seconds
The slowest run took 12.05 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
4.3 s ± 5.66 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

*Setting Read Preference to SECONDARY*

```
%%timeit
#html_collection = html_collection.with_options(read_preference=ReadPreference.SECONDARY)
print(html_collection.read_preference)
start = time.time()
print(len(list(html_collection.find())),'documents')
end = time.time()
print(end - start,'seconds')

Secondary(tag_sets=None, max_staleness=-1)
29 documents
2.0033063888549805 seconds
Secondary(tag_sets=None, max_staleness=-1)
29 documents
2.0986859798431396 seconds
Secondary(tag_sets=None, max_staleness=-1)
29 documents
2.555142879486084 seconds
Secondary(tag_sets=None, max_staleness=-1)
29 documents
1.7047474384307861 seconds
Secondary(tag_sets=None, max_staleness=-1)
29 documents
2.078212261199951 seconds
Secondary(tag_sets=None, max_staleness=-1)
29 documents
2.042281150817871 seconds
Secondary(tag_sets=None, max_staleness=-1)
29 documents
2.972836971282959 seconds
Secondary(tag_sets=None, max_staleness=-1)
29 documents
2.549753189086914 seconds
2.29 s ± 394 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: `nearest` chooses the one with the lowest latency, however that doesn't guarantee that the chosen replica is not busy (assuming the primary is chosen), choosing `secondary` ensures you're using the "free" replica that has no write work and is read ready, hence the performance improvement.

Comment: @tomslabbaert Any input on disabling Causal Consistency?

Comment: Full disclosure i have never turned it off as i care about consistency, if you don't care receiving data that might be inconsistent due to fresh write i'd say it's not a bad idea to turn it off for read sessions